# How to apply CSS to text that is NOT inside a certain tag?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

(All but div) {
padding-left: 100px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color: blue;">This is a div</div>
This is not a div

</body>
</html>
```

What could I replace (All but div) with to apply 100px padding on the left to the text, "This is not a div", without moving actual blue div itself?

[image: Example I quickly threw together in ms paint]

Comment: I think there are better ways of approaching the look you are going for but you could: body{ margin-left: 100px;} .bluediv{padding-left:-100 px;}

Comment: This isn't really possible without a second rule to "undo" the effect on the nested `div`.

Comment: I would simply use a **different** div and target that. It's a bad idea to apply wonky CSS directly to Body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply CSS in that way, but you could use negative margins:

```css
body {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
    
div {
  margin-left: -100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>This is a div</div>
  This is not a div
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will mark your answer as correct as soon as it will let me!

Answer (score 2):

There is no CSS selector for "This is not a div" because CSS selectors cannot target DOM `#text` nodes, only elements and pseudo-elements (e.g. `::before` and `::first-line`).

But you can do this:

```
body {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

body > div {
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Saying CSS cannot target DOM is rather incorrect...It literally uses the DOM to find and select specific elements to apply styles to.

Comment: @CaliCo I said CSS cannot target DOM `#text` nodes, not that it "cannot target DOM".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the elements within your application/site, you also can simply use the :not selector, which is actually an existing selector via CSS.

For example the following CSS...

```
div *:not(p) em {…}
```

Will selects all em elements that are in an element (that is not a p element) and that are in a div element. So in this case `<div><strong><em>…</em></strong>` is a match, but `<div><p><em>…</em></p></div> is not.`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use margin like that on body as it may interfere with other things you might want to do.  You should target the css so it's as local as possible.  Use span and then add left margin or padding

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

(All but div) {
padding-left: 100px;
}
span{
margin-left:50px;
padding-left:50px;
border:solid 1px black;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color: blue;">This is a div</div>
<span>This is not a div</span>

</body>
</html>
```