# Css selector of parent text

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I want to get this figure $185,000,000. Is there any way to get text from parent tag and avoiding text from child tags

```
<div class="txt-block">
            <h4 class="inline">Budget:</h4>
                $185,000,000
            <span class="attribute">(estimated)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can apply css to something not inside tags, try the answer on this question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887923/how-to-apply-css-to-text-that-is-not-inside-a-certain-tag

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="txt-block">
            <h4 class="inline">Budget:</h4>
            <span class="value">$185,000,000</span>
            <span class="attribute">(estimated)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Simply write

`response.css('.txt-block::text').extract_first()` 
This will return only `$185,000,000`. If you put space between `::` and `.txt-block`. This extract the text of children also